# aiohttp timeout doesn't work properly

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have code, that make http-requests to sites (using aiohttp) with async_timeout. If I run all requests together, then some requests are raising TimeoutError (even if timeout=20s.). But if I run one request -- it works.

```
def coro(url):    
    with async_timeout.timeout(TIMEOUT, loop=loop):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
           text, status = (await response.text()), response.status
    ...
```

Is this async_timeout problem/bug or my?

I tried to use TCPConnector (`aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=None, verify_ssl=False, loop=loop)`), but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing strange if a request takes more than 20 sec in case of very large requests amount (and this request is much faster when executed alone).

To make sure just insert timestamp printouts before and after `.get()`/`.text()` execution.

Timeout's code is deadly simple and highly tested, don't suspect an error in it.

Comment: Thanks you. How I can improve perfomance of this script? Use multiprocessing or multiple vps?

Comment: I have benchmark request time, it's like 0.1-0.3 seconds

Comment: Sorry, but your question is too broad. I cannot suggest anything without even looking on source code.

Comment: Can I write to your email? (or other communication?)

Comment: andrew dot svetlov at gmail dot com